# How to launch a Spring Batch job after startup?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

How can I run a job configured using `Spring-Batch` right after application startup?

Currently I'm specifying an exact time using cron job, but that requires to change the cron every time I restart the application:

`@JobRegistry`, `@Joblauncher` and a `Job`.
I execute the job as follows:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "${my.cron}")
public void launch() {
    launcher.run(job, params);
}
```

Comment: try to check Spring LifecycleProcessor

Comment: Could you just put the `launcher.run()` command into your main() method?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention I'm running the app inside a tomcat web application server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking aroud Spring code I have found [SmartLifecycle](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/context/SmartLifecycle.html)

> An extension of the Lifecycle interface for those objects that require
>   to be started upon ApplicationContext refresh and/or shutdown in a
>   particular order. The isAutoStartup() return value indicates whether
>   this object should be started at the time of a context refresh.

Try creating a custom bean implementing `SmartLifecycle` and setting `autoStartup`; when this custom bean start method is invoked launch your job.

Answer (score 1):

A few options that I can think of on the places to put your startup logic:

.1. In a bean `@PostConstruct` annotated method, reference is here - http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-postconstruct-and-predestroy-annotations

.2. By implementing an [ApplicationListener](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationListener.html), specifically for either [ContextStartedEvent](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/event/ContextStartedEvent.html) or ContextRefreshedEvent. Reference here - http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#context-functionality-events